# Start and Stop VisualSVN Server batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, svn, windows-server, visualsvn-server

how can stop and start a `VisualSVN Server` via batch/console (windows) command?

My Setup:

- VisualSVN Server 3.2
- Subversion 1.8.11
- Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VisualSVN Server 3.2 has 3 Windows services and each of them has to be stopped separatly:

- *VisualSVN Server* (`VisualSVNServer`): HTTP service,
- *VisualSVN Distributed File System* (`vdfsscv`): the service provides [multisite replication for Subversion repositories](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) (the service not enabled by default),
- *VisualSVN Repository Configurator* (`vrepocfgsvc`): the service provides [Repository Management Delegation feature](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/delegation/) (the service not enabled by default).

Some examples below.

---

**Using VisualSVN Server's WMI provider (via PowerShell):**

Start HTTP service:

```
$service = Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\VisualSVN -ClassName VisualSVN_Service -Filter "Name = 'VisualSVNServer'"
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $service -MethodName StartService
```

Stop HTTP service:

```
$service = Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\VisualSVN -ClassName VisualSVN_Service -Filter "Name = 'VisualSVNServer'"
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $service -MethodName StopService
```

**Using SC.exe from `cmd.exe` command prompt:**

Stop VisualSVN Server's HTTP service: `sc stop VisualSVNServer`,

Start VisualSVN Server's HTTP service: `sc start VisualSVNServer`.

[TechNet | `sc` command-line reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995).

Comment: Would be great if there were a cmdlet in VisualSVN PowerShell module to start/stop. Especially because in version 3.9.5 yet another service got added: _VisualSVN Background Job Service_ (`vsvnjobsvc`).

Comment: Why use VisualSVN WMI Provider instead of native PowerShell cmdlets: Stop-Service, Start-Service and Restart-Service?